# Can not display form in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I made a from, but for some reason it not show up when I try to display it. My forms supposed to collet information for blood donation.
I did it by following tutorial, and in the tutorial, it just showed up,
same as in any other tutorial I looked at after.

My `models.py`

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class donate(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    doner_ID = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    blood_types = [
        ('A+','A+'),
        ('B+','B+'),
        ('AB+','AB+'),
        ('O+','O+'),
        ('A-','A-'),
        ('B-','B-'),
        ('AB-','AB-'),
        ('O-','O-'),
    ]
    blood_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=blood_types,
        default=blood_types[0],
    )
    donation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

My `forms.py`

```py
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import donate

class donationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = donate
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'doner_ID', 'blood_type')
```

my views.py

```
from .forms import donationForm
from .models import donate

def donation(request):
    form=donationForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return render(request, 'main\donation.html', {'from':form})
    else:
        return render(request, 'main\donation.html', {'from':form})
```

The `donation.html` page

```
{% extends 'main\design.html'%}
{% block design %}

{{ errors }}

<form  action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-block">Submit</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Do you see any error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
def donation(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = donationForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('Succes-Page')
    else:
        form = donationForm()
    return render(request, 'main\donation.html', {'from':form})
```

[django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/)

Comment: hi, thamks for your help.
i try it, now i am getting error messages:


ValueError at /donation
The view main.views.donation didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: You can either `redirect` user to some page or return a `http response` after you successfully submitted the `form`. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do what Ganyen said but add

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
```

and:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
```

after `form.save()`

Comment: i try this as well, still the same error message:The view main.views.donation didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead..
thank you for helping!

Comment: that means there's an error in your form during validation, try adding `else print(form.errors)` in your `if form.is_valid()` block and share the error messages

Answer (score 0):

Ganyen answer is correct, but you need to return something after validating form

```
def donation(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = donationForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('your_url')
    else:
        form = donationForm()
    return render(request, 'main\donation.html', {'from':form})
```

Comment: i try this as well, still the same error message:The view main.views.donation didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

```
from .forms import donationForm
from .models import donate

def donation(request):
    form=donationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #Perform Custom logic
    else:
        form = donationForm()
    return render(request, 'main\donation.html', {'form':form})
```

The problem with your views was that you didn't declare it properly and spelt `form` as `from`. This above view should render out your form